# Mouse and Keyboard not working in XWindows

Tags: linux-from-scratch

I have an LFS v10 environment that is SystemV based. I'm in the process of improving it by adding XWindows to it. When I run startx, XWindows starts up, and I see the a few programs/Windows that display in the twm Window manager.

My problem is that the cursor does not move on the screen. I can see it in the dead center of the screen but it doesn't move as I move the mouse.

I also have a with the keyboard. It does appear that one of the programs/Windows are active by default at the time that XWindows starts, but an attempt to type some characters puts nothing in the text editor program.

The keyboard is a Logitech MK710 and the mouse is a Logitech M317.

Before I attempt to start XWindows, the keyboard works without problem while I'm working at the command line.

I've been activating different options when building the Linux kernel that some people are recommending but none are helping.

Comment: I forgot to mention that both the mouse and keyboard are wireless  USB based devices.

Comment: Another point to mention, is that my machine is set up for dual boot, with Ubuntu and LFS.  When I boot into Ubuntu, thise same mouse and keyboard work without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. For anyone interested. the solution was installing all 4 of the below drivers:

- libevdev-1.9.1
- Xorg Evdev Driver-2.10.6
- libinput-1.16.1
- Xorg Libinput-0.30.0

I then ran the `X -configure` command, then copied the created file to /etc/X11/xorg.conf, then ran startx and the mouse and keyboard began working.

Comment: I should also mention that I changed to a mouse and keyboard that were wired “not wireless” to rule that out as part of the issue.  i haven’t retested wi the wireless keyboard and mouse again, but I suspect that hey were not the issue and would work now.